# How to find correctly predicted test set images by using Tensorflow/Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

How can I find correctly predicted test set images? (like store those image into a folder/or know their filenames) Thanks in advance. :)

I was using ImageDataGenerator for the test dataset, the code is:

```
image = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=15,
                           width_shift_range=0.05,
                           height_shift_range=0.05,
                           rescale=1/255,
                           shear_range=0.05,
                           zoom_range=0.05,
                           horizontal_flip=True,
                           fill_mode='nearest'
                           )
test_image = image.flow_from_directory(test_path,
                                       target_size=image_shape[:2],
                                       color_mode='grayscale',
                                       batch_size=20,
                                       class_mode='binary', 
                                       shuffle=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are attributes of the generator you can use

```
filenames= test_image.filename # is an ordered list of the files as produced by the generator
labels=test_image.labels # is an ordered list of the labels for each file
class_dict=test_image.class_indices # is a dictionary of the form {classname: class index}
```

I usually reverse the class_dict so the class index is the key and the class name is the value. Code is

```
for key,value in class_dict.items():
        new_dict[value]=key    # dictionary {integer of class number: string of class name}
    
classes=list(new_dict.values())  # is a list of class names in order
```

Note the order of the files presented to model.fit is the same order as the filenames and labels only if in flow_from_directory you set shuffle=False. This is common practice when submitting generators to model.predict .

Comment: So what I need to do next is to compare the labels with the model.predict(test_image), then based on the order I can get the filename. Is this right?

Comment: yes do preds = model.predict on the test set. Then do a loop. through preds  as in  the code,  for i, p in enumerate(preds): then compare p to labels[i]